# cairngorm vs mate framework comparison in flex

Tags: apache-flex, cairngorm, mate

I have been developing applications in cairngorm framwork in flex for over 2 years.
Now I have to develop applications using Mate framework. I have no idea about Mate framework and which one is better than the other. I also need to know where to start to learn Mate framework, if somebody has idea about both the frameworks, kindly throw the light on this area.

Comment: http://aparnachaudhary.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/mate-vs-cairngorm/ this might  be help full

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely if you've been working with one of the older versions of Cairngorm, you're going to have a hard time getting out of the mindset of reaching out and touching the Framework from everywhere that's induced by its Singleton based architecture.  What you'll want to retain from what you've learned is your respect for event based communication. Probably not much else will be useful to you if you've been using the old Cairngorm.  If you've been using CairnGorm 3, you will likely find yourself right at home, because Mate and Parsley are very conceptually similar, and Mate developers tend to perfer the Presentation Model pattern.

Here's a great video that will help you understand Mate at a conceptual level http://tv.adobe.com/watch/360flex-conference/mate-flex-framework-by-laura-arguello/ .

Here are some articles of mine that you might frind useful as well http://www.developria.com/2010/05/mate-for-framework-beginners.html 
http://www.developria.com/2010/05/refactoring-with-mate.html

Unfortunately the source code is not available at this time, as my subdomain that hosted them is down.

Comment: Isn't Mate still view based for the events?  That doesn't bode well for me.

Comment: Mate encourages use of the Presentation Model, which means that you can choose to dispatch on the event bus.

Comment: Gotcha, must be newer because when I used it everything was event map based on the view. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Check out this article, which has been around for a while now http://www.developria.com/2010/02/photo-gallery-mate-framework-w.html

Comment: I agree with Amy, it is also event driven framework. So in my point of view mate is more flexible than cairngorm.

Answer (score -1):

Quick answer, don't use either.  They're both view based frameworks which are more of a hassle than anything.  Use Parsley or RobotLegs.  Parsley is more robust, but "heavier" with a steeper learning curve.  RobotLegs is smaller and simpler, but less flexible.

Cairngorm 3 is dependent on the Parsley extension framework.

I prefer Parsley because I seldom come to a Flex project that isn't large and needs a good way to be able to manage it.  It's the most use Flex framework in the financial industry.  There's a vibrant developer community and the lead developer is awesome.  It's also open source.

Comment: thanks , I have decided to start project in Mate now. It looks simple than Cairngorm and has lots of tutorials and docs available on internet.

Comment: I would agree with J_A_X that Robotlegs is a better Framework and has much better current support and documentation (though the OP sounded like it wasn't his decision to use Mate). I'd say if you have the power to make of influence the decision, Mate is the better one to go with.

MPO is that Robotlegs has more guidance than Parsley to keep developers from trying to go "around" the Framework, so it's probably a better way to go if your organization doesn't have much experience with Frameworks that aren't based on Singletons.